# How do I increase the tickCount for temporal axes in vega-lite

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite

I have a [vega-lite chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQspAjhoQpCvzgBGOADYALACYDAdn5MAZtYAc-I0fMAGK3aaXru8wE4xFkh2YubqSoJIAJ5wAE5oANqgEdFxqIkgcLJQbAAmNLJkaKCRRSBIAB40EKXWbDHImBoKlCbWiiB1NJmN6IJw1o0AvkrWXYI5GsRIggxhINDT6qigmJE4SyDCsnBIcYP7Sji7qtVpoCpqGn1kmTkA+hBwfVCNSkz5E73kt+2Pzz2gUZPHKneIgADWcBKAF0lKt1hocGx8kNBrCQMgYuDSkiUWhMDFZkoUbEkRFMBstjs4nC1htcbIhnCYkhZBBavUEoCaIIKalucCNJCSko5HAAPJtNIgAAibAA7rItuCAAQAChicCRMQpOQAlO0AMLTKAMclwHIqgAKJjERpNZqQuutYhc9sEpvNlqt5jt0P2-vRmWyeQKpWygjqpRkOoSsoVSvyqo1WrquoNSmNHsdzptdszDq9LrdBezRZ9fpGY0+EKh7UwdD6aFkZsEtIR6FkbAQ+Wmvygi1KLIKSzBMAgETVKpVLgU04MYgApHOxLplzPKL4MyAAMQ5OBwGzmdo73xwAd6E8AZl0dhMTAm-uGHSOUDoJWWIGysjyDbkOOOBArm+H8Hiec9Xk0aZZjQXRnymGYlhcFp9mGUBg1yfJCk-TA2DYXkaBwLkQA5BoNEXABFBBqirQV0AQNgmDuHVIIbTAm3QFUACUABUePVajt3hDYKQQbU+zQki6jI9BmladogXGDQ5UVZV1U1bV03rRsNhVFTE1kZMNLTC0hLpDQAEcGFZNinRoUgQEk0inSaFo2lopT0CzT0nQta1bW09jdO8nM-LzetzPQKybLoOyHKc6SXNktyFOrDQQvLV1Ao4kAVQy3zvSy9sNmixlYobeKFEBRKekUFKPJrfLc19bLgsLArrRa4rLOssrMDi9Q0VFV933DORf3YeRPyOFkgPQGA2FIGkoMQtBkKvJREBwVY0GsaZHng6CkIOEAZpOYiLg2Balt+cCXlKbZdjgCAegJIkSOrUEMUY5jsBAdF-3otgGEeRbYgijtTuRRlHKGjFdmxaboZ6PbBEeJQXpiNhIQ0Hc7HxiGNkJJsA02rJMLDT9ylKCoqhqGryKomjNiQJgngAZS1Y4-ymsRwlZp5xSWiIiPQGbRrhGgoHBQ1gZh1A+Y6GIunlkAmDYbBu0cjG02bVsGo0BimJY1qNF4-i1UEwmNFE8TBG1kAPxWHSNAAIVZHJ5RoHJ6AEpg8DMyHStsirBufEHYjUfrSkQNmcnFbbJtOUAcgTSMkByAAxHk4AAOVUDZU9UpN+GICArA9r2fZgWGlByJ0UE-BDZlBUAjd+npXSUfS1JTTTTLQCQxCvVd-GHlxzDMW1zFLHzcwC1BdBaX1Z9Cwq3VQXxKB8RWmrClrUFtSgxEk9uTcXlxZ3jYvDPU1MdQHhXKCvAxfAMEwX7EMRfF0K9fHMOwq9ywL2Qs4Xe7VcxZSfjPEAe9vQH10AYZ+vpT4-XProLu18DJGXvlpJ+JhzC3lMLoFwYgzA3jEIA2BECwogJaEAjqVooFXkoCvahZZGEIOQmQk+VVvrGz+ofS+3c05Jjvv3fUg9l7ENIeQjBADfAMPnnaVAoDbRKLCsw5e4COHNRUXYSgd5eFtzQYI20V8e5iL7iZSRqAWELivKQq8RgR66F0EYV0RgNHejoQQnRc9NEbxMJQMB3jOoqKQf4VBAieiOIsaI2+1iH62KXi4vwN4XDOKMHeX0wQwnhVUfQ9hAT16wVYfkg+EgUF8LPoIke8Sb44IkQaRelAXAYN8C4Tp3Sum9MUcUte-kVHIV0OogZmUN5Lw2uMzhKijAhOqSYmJaAjDCKwb3YyySWlLxcO-fxgyCkjLGXA4sZTjk0PgXMlotpokdxWZgyxiTNl4KXhg-JdC3kzMgZM7RFSrmkNuefV0DTsHiJsdskJ7zhnP3yVApebCTkVikSEYx-C7kKweQkpp4KyleK+bQ6F0zEVwtYfs8slTKB7MBYIgwazHnYq2biy+zKWWst0FCtavz8WlNaQii54SpGT1RbUnoC4QUbNwY-VJrKZXMvZdyoZnK-Gwp+XYPluj94ROftSnorhxVWOeVKyFCrDnXLJYwklvhzkasuWgJBVKammN1ZixpYLGWtLxYiuhRL+VMKCdva1JSBWoHMGanVaA7B0qxW6l5ISTBGF8ImpNybE1UK9dC5VJqoHBJMIGg5B9Q2jOFU6iNLrQVJNjZ631dCq02tOYfFo5q9FoFDVEx1yzF6rP1U8yVtjkJ5uAcMlVnK02+oPiw8wiy0XoI8d2hleD+1NoJZy+VxKfmkL+SsuNxaO0YKja6itj9F0csKS4AdFqN7IX8Ju1A8y-HhsXl-OdMaj2NpPchM9S6eXIXVUGpFdjNxTpFbBWlz7D19rfSauhG6s2XsA1+4N8yFwPriWBw1EHPnps5RPBDfrOX-1wwfeZaqT7+mZKydk0liK1E8mCelL7JEcuHZuwMbwkDSzIFjBgP4NDyhgCIdo8AaBkCwGgZxV8q70FgqYIwgwgA) that has a temporal x-axis. The values are in milliseconds. I would like to display a tick every 100 milliseconds, but I cannot get vega to display more than 4 ticks.

What do I need to change on the x-axis specification to get this to happen?  I've also tried `{"interval": "millisecond", "step": 100}` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: It would be useful to explain what the changes needed are instead of just posting new JSON.  It looks like the main change is that the type needs to be "quantitative" instead of "temporal". So in that sense it does not solve the problem which is to increase tickCount for temporal axes.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear to be possible to set the number of ticks for a temporal axis, however an alternate solution can produce the same effect.

Changing the axis type to `quantitative`, and using a `labelExpr` to format the labels appropriately can then allow setting an arbitrary number for `tickCount` (or just use the default which is sane).

In the case above, we'd use something like this:

```
"x": {
    "type": "quantitative",
    "axis": {
        "format": ",d",
        "labelExpr": "format(datum.value, ',d') + 'ms'",
        "tickCount": 30
    }
}
```